# Mostrar códigos para usuário

Tags: javascript, jquery, estilo-de-codificação, syntax-highlight

Olá! Tenho um **fórum** e, nas **publicações** de meus usuários, eles podem adicionar **códigos** para exibi-los utilizando a tag bbcode **[code][/code]**.

Eu gostaria de saber como fazer para **estilizar** o código, igual acontece aqui no SOpt. Exemplo: Qualquer código que eu insira, ele irá aplicar cores, independente de ser php, html, javascript....

***Abaixo, uma imagem do meu exibidor de códigos, atualmente:***
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

***Como eu gostaria que fosse:***

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

## Minhas perguntas principais são:

- Como fazer isso
- Existe alguma biblioteca pronta que eu possa fazer uso?
- Isso deixará o carregamento da página mais lerdo/comprometido?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Isso chama-se *Syntax highlight* e há bibliotecas que fazem isso. Podes fazer isso no servidor ou no lado do cliente, de preferência assíncrono.

Um exemplo, usando a biblioteca [highlight.js](https://github.com/isagalaev/highlight.js) seria assim (com o código dentro de tags `pre` e `code`):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/styles/default.min.css">
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highlight.js/9.12.0/highlight.min.js"></script>
<script>
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

</script>

<pre><code>
function teste() { 
    return 123;
}

var nr = teste();
console.log(nr);
</code></pre>
```

Outro exemplo com [Prism.js](http://prismjs.com/)

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.6.0/themes/prism.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prism/1.6.0/prism.js"></script>

<pre><code class="language-js">
function teste() { 
    return 123;
}

var nr = teste();
console.log(nr);
</code></pre>
```

Depois podes defenir as core mais ou menos ao teu gosto.

Comment: Mais uma vez você respondendo exatamente o que eu desejava. Muito obrigado pela resposta e parabéns pelo bom desempenho!

Comment: @VME ótimo que pude ajudar!