# como criar Syntax Highlight - jquery - css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, syntax-highlight

Como que se cria um Highlight, marcação de cores, igual de um IDE se oque foi digitado é um comando? gostaria de criar uma textarea, sobrepondo uma div, ambos com mesmo tamanho, e ao digitar no textarea, o mesmo conteudo iria aparecer na div, porém com o highlight.

Estou querendo criar um IDE online, tipo o CODEPEN -> https://codepen.io/
E um editor de texto edtilo o CKEditor ->  https://www.drupal.org/project/ckeditor

Alguem saberia como funciona a lógica? Aceito frameworks, dicas de código, etc... Não quero código pronto, entao os comentários estão livres :P

ex:

```js
$('#codigo').keyup(function(){

  $('#highlight').html( $(this).val() );

});
```

```css
#editor{
float: left;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
background: red;
}
#codigo, #highlight{
font-family: arial;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 20px;
position absolute;
width: inherit;
height: inherit;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
border: none;
}
#codigo{
opacity: 0;
resize: none;
}
#highlight{
margin-top: -304px;
background: #e5e5e5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<div id="editor">
<textarea id="codigo">voce esta digitando em um textarea, mas aparecendo o conteudo em uma div... </textarea>
<div id="highlight">voce esta digitando em um textarea, mas aparecendo o conteudo em uma div... </div>
</div>
```

Comment: É isto que procuras? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/232490/129

Comment: Não exatamente... tem o sistema de highlight, mas não com o textarea, oque estou procurando é o highlight com um textarea sobrepondo... mas vou tentar adaptar ( gambiarra :P ) com jquery e sobrepor um textarea nesse codigo, enviando o valor para aquela tag code